# Replacing NAs witha new factor level in one column based on factor level in another column using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

```
DATA = data.table(col_1 = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A", "C")),
                  col_2 = factor(c("stuff", NA, NA, "stuff", NA, "different_stuff", NA)))
```

I have a big data set in which I would like to replace the `NAs` from `col2`, that correspond to `C` from `col1`, with a new factor level, e.g. `yet_another_stuff`. There are more `NAs` than there are observations with `C` level and I don't want to replace the `NAs` that belong to other level like `B`.

After uploading this data set the columns are already of class factor.

I would highly prefer to do so using `data.table` package due to the size of the data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can specify the logical condition in `i` and assign those values in 'col_2' that corresponds to the condition with 'yet_another_stuff'

```
DATA[is.na(col_2) & col_1 == "C", col_2 := "yet_another_stuff"]
```